# Directive with isolated scope unexpectedly accessing parent scopes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have created a directive `my-directive` with isolated scope, but it looks like it is able to access property `div1` of `$rootScope` and property `div2` of its parent scope `$scope` of `controller1`.

What am I missing?

**Javascript:**

```
angular.module('app', [])
        .controller('controller1', ['$scope',
            function ($scope) {

            }])
        .directive('myDirective', [
            function () {
                return{
                    restrict: 'A',
                    replace: true,
                    scope: {
                        myDirective:'='
                    }
                };
            }]);
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div id="1" ng-app="app" ng-init="div1='div1'">
        <div id="2" ng-controller="controller1" ng-init="div2='div2'">
            <div id="4" my-directive="value" ng-init="div4='div4'">
                {{div4}}<br/>
                {{div1}}<br/>
                {{div2}}<br/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Output:**

```
div4
div1
div2
```

Comment: Where inside the directive are you trying to access those other values?

Comment: @MattWay, I am trying to access other scopes within <div id="4"></div>. I have declared my-directive on this div. So I guessed this div gets a scope isolated within its tags.

Answer (score 0):

The scope is isolated within the directive's template. Give your directive a template or write a link function and you will see that the scope is isolated. When you are access the directive scope's ancestors, this is happening outside the directive and then the parsed html is being 'transcluded' into your directive template, which is otherwise empty.

It is an interesting question though. I had not until now realized that omitting the template of a directive is effectively the same as including `transclude: true, template: '<div ng-transclude></div>'` in the directive definition.

Though you didn't include two of these properties, you actually did this:

```
.directive('myDirective', [
        function () {
            return{
                restrict: 'A',
                replace: true,
                transclude: true,
                template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
                scope: {
                    myDirective:'='
                }
            };
        }]);
```

Also note `myDirective: '='` should be `myDirective: '@'` because it is just a string.

Answer (score 0):

You should use transclude function inside the directive, otherwise that values will be bound to parent scope. Check this: http://pucksart.com/transclude-big-mistery/